# Apache Nutch: I always want to fetch a specific url first and then other urls in the segment created

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to crawl a client web site.
Client has given an identification url with some code, which will validate us for crawling and expose certain details which by default won't be available for others.
I just need to hit that url first and then I can go to any product url and fetch the details.

In the seed I have injected that particular url.
For me crawling is working fine and I am able to crawl through.
Problem for me is that when I am creating the segments after the initial injection, the seed URL wont be fetch as it has already been fetched. Due to this I am not getting certain hidden details as the cookie is not being set.
I have also tried specifying the seed url certain meta data within the seed.txt 
for e.g.
 `http://www.example.com/ nutch.score=10 nutch.fetchInterval=60`

I want to know if there is a way in nutch to fetch a particular url first and then other urls in the segment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that it even works for the first segment (if I understand you correctly). The Fetcher normally runs in multiple Java processes (Hadoop tasks) on multiple machines, so cookies will only be set in one task.

I suggest you take a look at the http.enable.cookie.header configuration property. If the cookie value is static, you can use this to inject it with every URL.
You will also need to set urlmeta.tags to "Cookie" in order for this property to propagate to outlinks.

Otherwise, I suspect you'll need to change some code, possibly in FetcherThread.

Comment: Can you please explain me more on "You will also need to set urlmeta.tags to "Cookie" in order for this property to propagate to outlinks.". 
I was not able to find good examples on how to use these tags.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. As I asked in the initial question that is there a way to always fetch the seed URL first for any segment. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way, but as I wrote, you can modify the code to do that.

Comment: Regarding urlmeta plugin, you can find a short description in the [JavaDoc](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.14/org/apache/nutch/indexer/urlmeta/URLMetaIndexingFilter.html), or read an detailed explanation of how it works since [here](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample).